# Giving custom color

Tags: windows-phone-7

In my wp7 app, I have added some rectangles on a canvas. I have set some custom color to the Rectangle's Fill method. There are some TextBlocks also added on the canvas which will appear in the center of the Rectangle. When I run the app on emulator it works fine. It displays the correct color I have given in the code and the texts are also displayed.

But when I run it on device, the entire area on canvas in which I have added Rectangles turned to black and the texts are not displayed. I came to know that this happens because of "The standard controls will change their colors based on the user's theme, if you have hardcoded colors (e.g. backgrounds) this may cause your controls to become invisible". How will I give custom colors which do not change according to the user-theme?
(Note: I am using C# to create the entire application UI not using XAML).

Answer (score 0):

You will need to retemplate the controls you are using so that they look well with the hardcoded colors you chose.

Use Expression Blend to edit the control template conveniently. Please use XAML for this. That's what it is intended for. You should spend the time to learn this, if you want to build a successful Silverlight application.
[http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc278068(v=VS.95).aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc278068%28v=VS.95%29.aspx)

Also, we are discussing the same in this thread:
http://forums.create.msdn.com/forums/p/80279/485681.aspx#485681

Thanks,
Stefan Wick - Microsoft Silverlight